# Avoiding % and _ in SQL predicate

Tags: java, hazelcast

The following code to search a particulate data in the map  is not working when the **searchWord** contains ***%,',_, etc***

```
StringBuilder fullQuery= new StringBuilder().
                 append("Name like \'").append(searchWord).
                 append("%\'");

List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) personMap
                .values(new SqlPredicate(fullQuery));
```

How can I use those symbols for actual match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast SQL like queries do not have Variable binding like Hibernate. You would have to do that on your own. You might want to store the statement in a constant and use String::format to replace variables.